# Les nouvelles en français avec les transcriptions

Tags: ressources, oral

Pour améliorer ma compétence d'écoute, je voudrais suivre les nouvelles en français. Ainsi, je cherche une chaîne qui fournit la transcription pour l'audio et la vidéo. Jusqu'à présent, je n'ai pu trouver que [Le Journal en français facile](http://www.rfi.fr/lffr/statiques/accueil_apprendre.asp) sur RFI. Pourtant, je voudrais écouter en français au niveau standard ou difficile.

Par exemple, j'ai trouvé [Le Journal de TV5Monde](http://www.tv5mondeplus.com/emission/journal-tv5monde?nid=436673Il). Le mot « Transcription » apparaît dans la page, mais rien ne se passe quand j'y clique.

Pourriez-vous proposer ou suggérer d'autres chaînes ou sites Internet ?

Comment: On ne modifie pas entièrement une question après l'avoir posée. Surtout lorsque quelqu'un s'est déjà donné la peine de répondre.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Merci de m'éclairer. J'ai posé une autre question de nouveau.

Comment: La première question était a propos des nouvelles, et tu as reçu une réponse. Si tu as une autre question il faut la poser séparément.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'en connais malheureusement pas qui fasse de la transcription, mais ces deux là pourraient vous aider :

- [France Info](http://www.franceinfo.fr/), qui propose une même info en version audio et en version texte. Sans être identiques, les deux sont souvent très proches. Si vous ne comprenez pas l'un, vous pourrez vous aider avec l'autre je pense. Et de toutes façons France Info emploie toujours les mêmes mots, donc au bout d'un moment cela devrait être facile de traduire.
- [Arte radio](http://www.arteradio.com/), qui ne répond pas du tout à votre question, mais qui propose des reportages très agréables à l'oreille, des sons, des paroles et bruitages très clairs, et souvent avec des personnes comme tout le monde ; j'imagine que pour l'apprentissage de la langue ce sera plus facile dans ces conditions.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé. Je viens d'approfondir la question, outre les nouvelles. Prière de m'informer d'autres informations.

Answer (score 0):

Après avoir tenté https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&hs=Be6&rls=org.mozilla%3Afr%3Aofficial&q=francais+transcriptiosn+ecouter+web&oq=francais+transcriptiosn+ecouter+web&gs_l=serp.3..33i21.2683.4654.0.5244.11.11.0.0.0.1.100.729.10j1.11.0....0...1c.1.35.serp..1.10.661.eoqetr-6D6g, je suis tombé sur http://www.lingq.com/forum/16/14775/ qui renferme :

7 jours sur la planète
http://www.tv5.org/TV5Site/7-jours/
(Chaque semaine, on peut écouter trois articles y compris des transcription ainsi que des leçons pédagogiques. Si vous vous êtes déjà abonné au TV5, vous pouvez regarder des informations hebdomadaires sous-titrés sur Internet.)

podcast français facile
http://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/
(Presque toutes les leçons sont faciles à suivre.)

M6
http://news.fr.msn.com/m6-actualite/video/
(Je trouve que les informations pas trop durs à suivre par rapport aux autres stations de TV.)

France Culture
http://www.franceculture.fr/
(Vous pouvez trouver des certaines programmes pas trop durs à suivre si vous écoutez cette station de radio toute la journée.) - See more at: http://www.lingq.com/forum/16/14775/#sthash.RbIasGjn.dpuf

http://french.hdsi.pl/top-49-learn-french-sites...#sthash.RbIasGjn.dpuf